# Excel VBA - Copy range from one sheet paste to all sheets after certain sheet in workbook

Tags: vba, excel, loops, paste

I feel like this is too simple to be stuck on, but I have a workbook with about 100 sheets, and I need to copy a range from one sheet (Sheet2 Range a1:H200) to Sheet5 AF1:AM200 and every sheet after (Sheet5 through Sheet100 or more).  I have tried creating a loop and copying the original range and pasting to each sheet, but it hasn't worked.  I feel like this is the closest I've gotten

```
Sub CopyPasteLoop()

Dim wsVar As Worksheet

For Each wsVar In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
   With wsVar
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:H200").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("AF1").Value
   End With
Next wsVar

End Sub
```

I feel like it should be simpler, but I can't make it work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there. Try this:

```
Sub CopyPasteLoop()

Dim wsVar As Worksheet

Dim i as Integer
For i = 5 to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("AF1:AM200").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:H200").Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Or for better performance, use this:

```
Dim vRange as Variant
vRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).range("A1:H200")

Dim i as Integer
For i = 5 to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("AF1:AM200").Value = vRange
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks!  This made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully @Scott Holtzman's answer will work for you (providing your sheets are indexed in the same order as they're named). This approach will also work.

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set rng = wb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:H200")

For Each ws In wb.Sheets

    If CInt(Right(ws.Name, Len(ws.Name) - Len("Sheet"))) >= 5 Then

        ws.Range("AF1:AM200").Value = rng.Value

    End If

Next ws
```